# what is the simplest way to get element content by XPath with Python?

Tags: python, xpath

I need to get content for this XPath:

```
/html/body/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]
```

It's copied from FireBug. How can I do this? I have a very large HTML document, so I don't want (and don't know how:) ) to grep it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) can handle html (and provides pretty good xpath support):

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> tree = lxml.html.parse('test.html')
>>> for node in tree.xpath('/html/body/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]'):
...     print node.text
...          
first row, second column
second row, second column
```

Just make sure that you use it's [html parser](http://codespeak.net/lxml/lxmlhtml.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! That works fine. I have found similar solution but it should work also in cases if needed text is not in old xpath anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
import lxml.html as h
tree = h.parse("keys_results.html")
text = tree.xpath("string(//*[contains(text(),'needed_text')])")
print text
```